# Jquery issue in ie7 and ie8

Tags: jquery

I have a problem in jQuery in IE7 and IE8. In all other browsers the script is working fine.

When I copy to clipword I found this error:

> **Webpage error details**
>
> **User Agent**: `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
>   Timestamp: Mon, 3 Oct 2011 11:24:50 UTC`
>
> **Message**: `Could not get the position property. Invalid argument.
>   Line: 16 Char: 79183 Code: 0 URI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js`
>
> **Message**: `Could not get the position property. Invalid argument. Line:
>   16 Char: 79183 Code: 0 URI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js`

If I try with the full, non-minified jQuery ([1.5.1](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js)) it still produces the error.

The website is located [here](http://indivar.info/AnimatedContentMenu/). When you click on `Collection` then two images open when you click on one of images. Then, you will able to see the exact problem.

Comment: It has to do with some call you make from within your script to jQuery. You need to find out which call it is.

Answer (score 3):

When I viewed the link I go an error `Could not get the position property. Invalid argument.` I tracked it down through the stack trace and it appears that your problem comes from your `jquery.template.js` file in `animateHeadingDesc` function. In that function you make a call to `paramHeading.position='absolute';` which is not the correct usage of `.position()`.

[jQuery Position doc](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

It looks like you want to apply a CSS position property which can by applied by using something like `paramHeading.css('position','absolute');`

It also looks like you're trying to animate the element being set to `position:absolute` which I'm pretty sure jQuery can't do. It would be a good idea to set that first and then animate your element.

Answer (score 0):

I get alot of errors of missing images, for example when I click on a picture in the Collection.

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://indivar.info/AnimatedContentMenu/kitchen2/2.jpg"
2.jpg
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://indivar.info/AnimatedContentMenu/kitchen2/1.jpg"
1.jpg
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://indivar.info/AnimatedContentMenu/kitchen2/3.jpg"
3.jpg
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://indivar.info/AnimatedContentMenu/kitchen2/4.jpg"
4.jpg
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://indivar.info/AnimatedContentMenu/kitchen2/5.jpg"
5.jpg
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://indivar.info/AnimatedContentMenu/kitchen2/6.jpg"
```

I even get an undefined error when some script is trying to fetch something from an url

```
http://indivar.info/AnimatedContentMenu/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

Check which script is trying to get a value here, but returns undefined.

If you think that the jquery declaration is the problem, download the jquery source instead of taking it from google.

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js

Copy paste that into a file on your server and run it from there. Remember to declare the jquery before other scripts which depend on jquery.

Comment: hello i think you clicked on other image , Please click on one of image that is showing to you after just click on collection